# Transform HTML area to GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson, coordinates

I have this file http://www.meteofrance.com/mf3-rpc-portlet/js/datas/zones_AVDEPT73.json where the "zone" field is put in an area HTML element (so does "shape").

I have a little script that takes the zone and transform it into GeoJSON. Even if the GeoJSON is not at the right place here is the script:

```
from typing import Dict

def parse_geom(zone: str) -> Dict:
    geom = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': None}
    coords = zone.split(',')
    # we want the area to be projected in EPSG:4326. But lat need to be bound
    # in -180;+180 and long -90;+90.
    coords_int = [float(x)/100 for x in coords]
    geom['coordinates'] = [[coords_int[x+1], coords_int[x]] for x in range(0, len(coords_int)-1, 2)]
    geom['coordinates'] = [geom['coordinates']]
    return geom
```

Here is the result (in geojson.io)
[image]

Here is the entire script to downloads the file:

https://gist.github.com/RemiDesgrange/fd29aadb9493b1d7a88b7eb246a93425

I tried to rotate it via QGIS. But I don't understand what I see. It seems to me that this is a fairly simple math problem...

Comment: GeoJSON is not EPSG4326

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-4 yeah, ok...

Comment: That's right GeoJSON uses CRS:84 which is World Geodetic System 1984 ([epsg:6326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:datum:EPSG::6326)) with coordinates in long/lat order. 
 [EPSG:4326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) on the other hand uses coordinates in lat/long order

Answer (score 1):

On the theorical part, my question is not answered. But technicaly. I manage to get data right in Qgis by selecting all the geom, rotating by -90° and then swap X and Y.